Editing Apex Classes directly in Production Environment
I'm a new Admin in my Org, and I need to make a small change in an Apex Classes created by a third-part company to allow our Users to import data using CSV files using an Import button that has the the Apex Class behind it.
I was able to manage all changes in the code in our Sandbox environment, although when trying to deploy it using the Change Sets I simply can't bypass the Validation step because it encounters so many errors. Those errors are related to many many changes done in the past by other administrador that are now blocking the Test Apex Class from being approved.
I have even tried to manually fix every error pointe in the Validation step, but it didn't work as it had too many errors. Is there anyway or tool I can use to make the change directly in production?

No. It is not possible to edit compiled components in general directly in production. You should fix those issues and deploy the changes with passing tests that cover at least 75% of the code being deployed.
By "compiled components in general" think Aura and Lightning components, Visualforce pages and Apex classes.

A key insight here is that you don't need to run all tests in your org, just enough to get coverage for the things you're deploying. That said, you're just going to make things worse if you keep letting test failures pile up. May not be a glamorous job, but tests really are our best defense against preventing errors from popping up and data becoming dirty.
